# Access Outlook Editor Object

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

How to access the Outlook editor using com object.

I am making a c# .net app mail client and want to add an email editor similar to the outlook desktop application.

I am able to access the editor wordEditor object by using

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Word.Document document = oMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor;
```

This gives the com object not the complete editor.
I want the editor which can render this as well as add to this.

Is the outlook editor exposed through any api?

I dont wish to use a third party editor.

I want a text box in which text can be typed ,formattted ,drag dropped etc. But wanted to use the inbult outlook one.i was hoping it is exposed through some API .After getting the WordEditor how do I display it and then automatically add to it as text is typed in some formatted text box

Comment: What do you mean by "can render this as well as add to this"? What are you trying to do that that GetInspector.WordEditor is incapable of?

Comment: I wanted a text box in which text can be typed ,formattted ,drag dropped etc. But wanted to use the inbult outlook one.i was hoping it is exposed through some API .After getting the WordEditor how do I display it and then automatically add to it as text is typed in some formatted text box.

Comment: This link will help for you:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7393ccf-4b7e-4034-ba73-6d4e8fcb8c19/accessing-word-editor-for-inbox-window-in-outlook?forum=outlookdev

Comment: @AlinaLi The link doesnt show exactly what i want, i wanted a full editor , but using the Wordeditor object i will have to add text and formatting myself to the text by code.